# Convert Excel formula to Javascript with multiple Math.pow

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, excel-formula

I have the following formula in excel:

```
=B8*((1+((1+B9)^(1/12)-1))^12*(((1+B9)^(1/12))-1))/((1+((1+B9)^(1/12)-1))^12-1)
```

Where:

```
B8 = 1878
B9 = 17.9%
```

I get as a result = 170.91

How can I convert this to javascript?

I tried to use `Math.pow` but I am finding it difficult as the formula is complex.

Comment: Hi @Paco - if you post an example of what you've already attempted in javascript, then that will help others to assist you in understanding where you may have gone wrong so far.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "I see that there are several" .... in relation to Math.pow .... but if you're misinterpreting something about that function, then others will be able to assist you to understand and then you can achieve your desired result yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two major features to the calculation which repeat a lot in your Excel formula. You can define them upfront in a Javascript function to simplify the calculation:

`a`: The 12th root of (1 + `B9`), less 1: `Math.pow(1 + B9, 1 / 12) - 1`

`b`: The value from (a) plus 1, to the 12th power: `Math.pow(1 + a, 12)`

Then the simplified version of your formula is `B8 * (a * b) / (b - 1)`.

So your function can be per below where `B8` is `x`, `B9` is `y`, and `a` and `b` are per above:

```js
function foo(x, y) {
  const a = Math.pow(1 + y, 1 / 12) - 1;
  const b = Math.pow(1 + a, 12);
  return x * (a * b) / (b - 1);
}

const answer = foo(1878, 0.179);
console.log(answer);
```